# JavaScript seems to store answers I don't want stored

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm a little stumped and on a very interesting problem I've run into. I'm very new to the world of Full Stack web development so I'm not sure where to go from here exactly. Basically I'm creating a web based Sudoku game using mostly HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. What's going on is I've created functions to populate the HTML board and to solve the board. It should solve and populate the board when a button is clicked, but it seems to populate the board from the get go with the solved board before the click. Before I add in any code I just wanna say thank you in advance for any help and I'm personally wondering if it could be a sort of cache problem?

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sudoku</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
     integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Portfolio/CSS/Sudoku.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header">
      <h1 class="header__title">Sudoku</h1>
      <div class="header__options">
        <button class="header__newGame" type="submit" name="button">
          New Game
        </button>
        <button class="header__darkMode" type="button" name="mode">
          Dark Mode
        </button>

      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Sudoku Game Section -->
    <section class="sudoku">
      <table class='sudoku__board'>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sudoku__row">
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
          <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>

    <div class="sudoku__buttons">
      <button type="button" class="sudoku__submit">Submit Attempt</button>
      <button type="button" class="sudoku__solve">Solve Puzzle</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <a href="mailto:isaacstong90@gmail.com" class="footer__link">IsaacStong90@gmail.com</a>
      <ul class="social-list">
        <!-- LinkedIn -->
        <li class="social-list__item">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/isaacstong/" class="social-list__link">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <!-- GitHub -->
        <li class="social-list__item">
          <a href="https://github.com/IsaacStong" class="social-list__link">
            <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <!-- Instagram -->
        <li class="social-list__item">
          <a href="#" class="social-list__link">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </footer>

    <script src="{% static 'Portfolio/JS/Sudoku.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the JS:

```
// game boards for Sudoku.
const board1 = [
  [5, 3, '', '', 7, '', '', '', ''],
  [6, '', '', 1, 9, 5, '', '', ''],
  ['', 9, 8, '', '', '', '', 6, ''],
  [8, '', '', '', 6, '', '', '', 3],
  [4, '', '', 8, '', 3, '', '', 1],
  [7, '', '', '', 2, '', '', '', 6],
  ['', 6, '', '', '', '', 2, 8, ''],
  ['', '', '', 4, 1, 9, '', '', 5],
  ['', '', '', '', 8, '', '', 7, 9]
];

//Code for populating original board and buttons below board
populateBoard(board1);
solvedBoard = solve(board1);
document.querySelector('.sudoku__solve').addEventListener('click', populateBoard(solvedBoard));

//Checks board to see if user is correct
function checkBoard(board) {
  var k = 0;
  blocks = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
    //Checks to see if each space matches the solved board
      if (board[i][j] == blocks[k].value) {
        blocks[k].style.color = 'green'
        }
      else {
        blocks[k].style.color = 'red'
      }
      }
      k = k+1;
    }
}

//populates the HTML board with the given board
function populateBoard(board) {
  // Select all squares from HTML and populate using board.
  blocks = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  var k = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
      blocks[k].value = board[j][i];
      //if statement makes given Sudoku values gray and uneditable.
      if (blocks[k].value != '') {
        blocks[k].readOnly = true;
        blocks[k].style.color = 'gray';
      }
      k = k+1;
    }
  }
}

//Solve Board that has been selected
function solve(board) {
    let emptySpot = nextEmptySpot(board);
    let row = emptySpot[0];
    let col = emptySpot[1];

    // there is no more empty spots
    if (row === -1){
        return board;
    }

    for(let num = 1; num<=9; num++){
        if (checkValue(board, row, col, num)){
            board[row][col] = num;
            solve(board);
        }
    }

    if (nextEmptySpot(board)[0] !== -1)
        board[row][col] = '';

    return board;
}

//Finds empty space for the solve function
function nextEmptySpot(board) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] === '')
                return [i, j];
        }
    }
    return [-1, -1];
}

//Check to see if the row selection is valid
function checkRow(board, row, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < board[row].length; i++) {
        if(board[row][i] === value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//Check to see if the column selection is valid
function checkColumn(board, column, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if(board[i][column] === value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

function checkSquare(board, row, column, value){
    boxRow = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
    boxCol = Math.floor(column / 3) * 3;

    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++){
            if (board[boxRow + r][boxCol + c] === value)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};


function checkValue(board, row, column, value) {
    if(checkRow(board, row, value) &&
      checkColumn(board, column, value) &&
      checkSquare(board, row, column, value)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
document.querySelector('.sudoku__solve').addEventListener('click', populateBoard(solvedBoard));
```

When you are adding the function `populateBoard(solvedBoard)` like this, what happens is that you call it immediately. So what you'll have to do instead is this:

```
 document.querySelector('.sudoku__solve').addEventListener('click', () => populateBoard(solvedBoard));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going completely down a rabbit hole with this problem I thought it had something to do with pass by value vs. pass by reference